# How do I handle this exception

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am connecting to a database and I get an exception when I test it with invalid credentials. 
The codes for the connection are in a separate class and I am already catching the error there.

But it seems to go through that and have another exception directed at where I am calling the constructor which is at my mainWindow.xaml.cs. How do I handle this second exception. I did another try/catch at my MainWindow page and the exception persists. Please advice.

```
//Code at class SimpleDataSource which does the connection:

public void Connect(string server, string database, int port, string user, string password)
        {
            // TODO: Initialise MySqlConnection object with parameters,
            // open connection with suitable exception handling.
            string connStr = "server=" + server + ";database=" + database + ";port=" + port + ";user=" + user + ";password=" + password + ";";

            try
            {
                conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"Unable to connect to database. 
                                Please check the following and try again.
                                1. Ensure you have an internet connection.
                                2. Ensure your credentials are entered correctly");
                Console.WriteLine("The error is " + e);
            }

        } 

//Calling the constructor for that class on my MainWindow which is causing the exception:
SimpleDataSource dataSource;
try { dataSource = new SimpleDataSource("111.111.11.11", "eeeee", 3306, "eeeee", "eeee"); }
catch (MySqlException e) { e.StackTrace.ToString();}
```

Error Message: 
I tried to swap for XamlParseException instead of MySqlException and same results.
[image]

Comment: In your exception dialog, click on `Viewdetail` to check why the error is there. This exception (XamlParseException) comes on application load when some xaml file has incorrect xaml tags or property values used. You would need to make sure your xaml file has correct syntax.

Comment: @VS1 to double check, you mean my error is in my MainWindow.xaml page itself and not my class files?

Comment: Yes @Trevor_zam, it could be in your `MainWindow.xaml` file, as per error dialog check your xaml file's Line 3 and Column 9. Also see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlparseexception.aspx . Also, are you calling some other class in MainWindow.xaml file's constructor?

Comment: Nope SimpleDataSource is the only class I am calling. This is my xaml line 3 - xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml".

Comment: And it works with correct credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post any code that is contained within your MainWindow() constructor. Although the error point to that 3rd line in xaml, chances are the error is elsewhere. On your xaml.cs page, other than the constructor; are you are calling any function that talks to your database.

Look under your InitialiseComponent(). Are you calling any function there that interacts with the database. If yes, select those group of line and add breakpoints on them and run your application.